# Bash text from pattern to pattern multiline

Tags: bash, parsing, awk, sed, grep

I have a file with multiple code segments in it. The segments are separated by language using `(Language)` as a separator. I would like to be able to extract all segments of the same language (ignoring other segments).

I tried grepping for the language I wanted `(Python)` until the **NEXT** occurrence of a language separator, but it went to far. I think this syntax makes it go to the **LAST** occurrence of a language separator instead.

```sh
cat filename | tr '\n' '@' | grep '@(Python).*@([A-Z].*)' | tr '@' '\n'
```

I could do this quite easily with some *line by line* logic. I am looking for a simple `grep`, `awk`, or `sed` solution.

Input file:

```
(Axiom) [fibonacci(n) for n in 0..50]
(MAGMA) [Fibonacci(n): n in [0..38]];
(MAGMA) [0, 1] cat [n: n in [1..50000000] | IsSquare(5*n^2-4) or IsSquare(5*n^2+4)]; 
(Maxima) makelist(fib(n), n, 0, 100); 
(PARI) a(n) = fibonacci(n)
(PARI) a(n) = imag(quadgen(5)^n)
(PARI) a(n)=my(phi=quadgen(5)); (phi^n-(-1/phi)^n)/(2*phi-1) 
(PARI) a(n)=polcoeff(sum(m=0, n, x^m*prod(k=1, m, k+x +x*O(x^n))/prod(k=1, m, 1+k*x +x*O(x^n))), n) 
(Python) # From Jaap Spies, Jan 05 2007:
def fib():
    """ Generates the Fibonacci numbers, starting with 0 """
    x, y = 0, 1
    while 1:
        yield x
        x, y = y, x+y
f = fib()
a = [next(f) for _ in range(100)]
def A000045(n):
    """ Returns Fibonacci number with index n, offset 0 """
    return a[n]
def A000045_list(N):
    """ Returns a list of the first n Fibonacci numbers """
    return a[:N]
(Python) # As b-file:
from gmpy2 import fib
for n in range(100): print(str(n) + " " + str(fib(n)))  # Bruno Berselli, Dec 06 2016
(Sage) # Demonstration program from Jaap Spies:
a = sloane.A000045; # choose sequence
print(a)            # This returns the name of the sequence.
print(a(38))        # This returns the 38th number of the sequence.
print(a.list(39))   # This returns a list of the first 39 numbers.
(Sage) # Alternatively:
a = BinaryRecurrenceSequence(1, 1); print([a(n) for n in range(20)])
# Closed form integer formula with F(1) = 0 from Paul Hankin (use only for fun).
F = lambda n: (4<<(n-1)*(n+2))
print([F(n) for n in range(20)]) # Peter Luschny, Aug 28 2016
```

Desired output for `Python`:

```
(Python)# From Jaap Spies, Jan 05 2007:
def fib():
    """ Generates the Fibonacci numbers, starting with 0 """
    x, y = 0, 1
    while 1:
        yield x
        x, y = y, x+y
f = fib()
a = [next(f) for _ in range(100)]
def A000045(n):
    """ Returns Fibonacci number with index n, offset 0 """
    return a[n]
def A000045_list(N):
    """ Returns a list of the first n Fibonacci numbers """
    return a[:N]

(Python)# As b-file:
from gmpy2 import fib
for n in range(100): print(str(n) + " " + str(fib(n)))  # Bruno Berselli, Dec 06 2016
```

Desired output for `Sage`:

```
(Sage) # Demonstration program from Jaap Spies:
a = sloane.A000045; # choose sequence
print(a)            # This returns the name of the sequence.
print(a(38))        # This returns the 38th number of the sequence.
print(a.list(39))   # This returns a list of the first 39 numbers.

(Sage) # Alternatively:
a = BinaryRecurrenceSequence(1, 1); print([a(n) for n in range(20)])
# Closed form integer formula with F(1) = 0 from Paul Hankin (use only for fun).
F = lambda n: (4<<(n-1)*(n+2))
print([F(n) for n in range(20)]) # Peter Luschny, Aug 28 2016
```

Desired output for `PARI`:

```
(PARI) a(n) = fibonacci(n)
(PARI) a(n) = imag(quadgen(5)^n)
(PARI) a(n)=my(phi=quadgen(5)); (phi^n-(-1/phi)^n)/(2*phi-1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming it's just mistakes in your question that the expected output for `PARI` includes `(PARI)` but the output for `Python` doesn't include `(Python)` (and ditto for `Sage`) and that one of the `(PARI)` lines from the input is missing from the expected output.

The following will work using any awk in any shell on every UNIX box.

If you want the language name retained in the output then:

```
awk -v tgt='Python' -F'[()]' '/^\(/{f=(tgt==$2)} f' file
```

otherwise if you want it removed:

```
awk -v tgt='Python' -F'[()]' '{act=$2} sub(/^\([^()]+\) */,""){f=(tgt==act)} f' file
```

For example, retaining the `(<language>)`:

```
$ awk -v tgt='Python' -F'[()]' '/^\(/{f=(tgt==$2)} f' file
(Python) # From Jaap Spies, Jan 05 2007:
def fib():
    """ Generates the Fibonacci numbers, starting with 0 """
    x, y = 0, 1
    while 1:
        yield x
        x, y = y, x+y
f = fib()
a = [next(f) for _ in range(100)]
def A000045(n):
    """ Returns Fibonacci number with index n, offset 0 """
    return a[n]
def A000045_list(N):
    """ Returns a list of the first n Fibonacci numbers """
    return a[:N]
(Python) # As b-file:
from gmpy2 import fib
for n in range(100): print(str(n) + " " + str(fib(n)))  # Bruno Berselli, Dec 06 2016
```

.

```
$ awk -v tgt='Sage' -F'[()]' '/^\(/{f=(tgt==$2)} f' file
(Sage) # Demonstration program from Jaap Spies:
a = sloane.A000045; # choose sequence
print(a)            # This returns the name of the sequence.
print(a(38))        # This returns the 38th number of the sequence.
print(a.list(39))   # This returns a list of the first 39 numbers.
(Sage) # Alternatively:
a = BinaryRecurrenceSequence(1, 1); print([a(n) for n in range(20)])
# Closed form integer formula with F(1) = 0 from Paul Hankin (use only for fun).
F = lambda n: (4<<(n-1)*(n+2))
print([F(n) for n in range(20)]) # Peter Luschny, Aug 28 2016
```

.

```
$ awk -v tgt='PARI' -F'[()]' '/^\(/{f=(tgt==$2)} f' file
(PARI) a(n) = fibonacci(n)
(PARI) a(n) = imag(quadgen(5)^n)
(PARI) a(n)=my(phi=quadgen(5)); (phi^n-(-1/phi)^n)/(2*phi-1)
(PARI) a(n)=polcoeff(sum(m=0, n, x^m*prod(k=1, m, k+x +x*O(x^n))/prod(k=1, m, 1+k*x +x*O(x^n))), n)
```

and removing it:

```
$ awk -v tgt='Python' -F'[()]' '{act=$2} sub(/^\([^()]+\) */,""){f=(tgt==act)} f' file
# From Jaap Spies, Jan 05 2007:
def fib():
    """ Generates the Fibonacci numbers, starting with 0 """
    x, y = 0, 1
    while 1:
        yield x
        x, y = y, x+y
f = fib()
a = [next(f) for _ in range(100)]
def A000045(n):
    """ Returns Fibonacci number with index n, offset 0 """
    return a[n]
def A000045_list(N):
    """ Returns a list of the first n Fibonacci numbers """
    return a[:N]
# As b-file:
from gmpy2 import fib
for n in range(100): print(str(n) + " " + str(fib(n)))  # Bruno Berselli, Dec 06 2016
```

.

```
$ awk -v tgt='Sage' -F'[()]' '{act=$2} sub(/^\([^()]+\) */,""){f=(tgt==act)} f' file
# Demonstration program from Jaap Spies:
a = sloane.A000045; # choose sequence
print(a)            # This returns the name of the sequence.
print(a(38))        # This returns the 38th number of the sequence.
print(a.list(39))   # This returns a list of the first 39 numbers.
# Alternatively:
a = BinaryRecurrenceSequence(1, 1); print([a(n) for n in range(20)])
# Closed form integer formula with F(1) = 0 from Paul Hankin (use only for fun).
F = lambda n: (4<<(n-1)*(n+2))
print([F(n) for n in range(20)]) # Peter Luschny, Aug 28 2016
```

.

```
$ awk -v tgt='PARI' -F'[()]' '{act=$2} sub(/^\([^()]+\) */,""){f=(tgt==act)} f' file
a(n) = fibonacci(n)
a(n) = imag(quadgen(5)^n)
a(n)=my(phi=quadgen(5)); (phi^n-(-1/phi)^n)/(2*phi-1)
a(n)=polcoeff(sum(m=0, n, x^m*prod(k=1, m, k+x +x*O(x^n))/prod(k=1, m, 1+k*x +x*O(x^n))), n)
```

The 2nd script above sets the field separator to `(` or `)`, saves the actual language pulled from between those in a variable named `act`, removes the `(...)`, then sets a flag `f` to `1` (i.e. `true` in a condition context) if the actual language name from the input (saved in `act`) matches the target language name specified on the command line (saved in `tgt`) and `0` (`false`) otherwise. When that flag `f` is `1` (true) it invokes awks default action of printing the current input line. The 1st script is just a simpler version of the same since it doesn't have to remove the `(...)`.

Since the above is doing a string comparison (as opposed to a regexp comparison such as would be required by sed) it'll work as-is for any language name that does not contain a `'` or a backslash (FWIW I'm not aware of any programming language names that contain either and I don't see any at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_programming_languages). If that's an issue, the code can be tweaked to accomodate...

Comment: This solution is very thorough! Thank you very much for the explanation!

Comment: You're welcome. No, `act` is just a name I made up to save the current value of `$2` in before removing the substring containing `($2)`. I could've called it `tigerking` or anything else. From your recent question update it looks like you want to leave the language name in the output though so then you don't need that second script that uses `act` at all and you just need the first, simpler script.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '/^([^)]\+)/h;//b;G;/^(Python)/MP' file
```

Turn off implicit printing by using the `-n` option.

Copy the delimiter to the hold space (HS).

For any other line, append the delimiter line.

If the current line contains the required delimiter i.e. language, print the first line in the pattern space.

N.B. The `M` flag allows the regexp to match the exact delimiter and is GNU specific.

To keep the first line, just remove the second command:

```
sed -n '/^([^)]\+)/h;G;/^(Python)/MP' file
```

To remove the delimiter from the first line, use:

```
sed -n '/^([^)]\+)\s*/h;//s///;G;/^(Python)/MP' file
```

---

In overview: the line containing the delimiter `(Python)`, `(Sage)` or whatever `(...)`, is stored in another buffer called the hold space (HS). The HS is appended to each line. If the second line matches the intended delimiter the first line is printed `P`. As the `-n` option has been invoked, any lines that do not match the above criteria, will be forgotten.

Comment: This does exactly what I needed, thank you! Could you edit your solution and elaborate a bit more on what is going on in that ```sed``` script?

Comment: This script does not work for the _one liners_. How can I change this script to not delete the text on the same line as (Language) ?

Comment: Just watch out for language names that contain any regexp metacharacters or sed delimiters (e.g. `C*` or `C/AL`) since those will need to be handled in some way to avoid false matches or syntax errors.

Answer (score 0):

Just output only what `grep` matched, not the whole line.

```
<file tr '\n' '@' | grep -o '@(Python).*@([A-Z].*)' | tr '@' '\n
```

When filtering strange inputs, I sometimes (ab-)use `sed -z`:

```
sed -z 's/.*\(\n(Python).*\n([A-Z].*)[^\n]*\n\).*/\1/' file
```

You may interestt yourself in how to [filter lines between patterns in bash](https://www.google.com/q=filter+lines+between+patterns+bash).

Comment: That first `tr` will produce output that's no longer a POSIX text file and so relies on undefined behavior from the `grep` and it can create false matches if there's Sage code that says `print "I love @(Python)@etc"` or similar. grep will probably behave OK with the non-POSIX input and there probably aren't strings like that in the code for other languages so it's pretty low risk of breaking but it's kinda cludgey and then we come to the final `tr` which will convert any `@`s in the input to newlines which is pretty likely to cause breakage at some point.

Comment: You should mention that the sed solution requires GNU sed and will read the whole input file into memory. You also need to add something to handle `(Python)` being at the start of the input file rather than requiring it to be preceded by a newline. I'm also not convinced that the `.*` after it won't bite you by sucking up all lines before the final `([A-Z].*)`. I just tried it and it output the last `Python` lines (ignored everything before the last one courtesy of the first `.*` in the regexp) then a bunch of `Sage` lines.

Comment: You'd also need to escape regexp metacharacters (and delimiters in the sed case) in any language name that had them since both scripts are doing a regexp rather than a string comparison.